# System.Data.SqlClient and Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS )

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlclient

I have a question about the default value of the MultipleActiveResultSets parameter and System.Data.SqlClient.

The MSDN article about MARS states that the default value of MultipleActiveResultSets parameter in a connection string is false, and, unless specifically set to True, the MARS capability is disabled.

Although I came across a few posts online which indicates that when using System.Data.SqlClient it enables MARS be default, unless the user specifically sets MultipleActiveResultSets=false on the connection string, Which means that if this paramter is omitted from the connection string, MARS capability is enabled.

I was just wondering: when using SqlClient without specifing the   MultipleActiveResultSets parameter in the connection string, does MARS capability is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is false, per the docs [SqlConnection.ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), which makes sense as MultipleActiveResultsets was a new feature in SQL Server 2005, and System.Data.SqlClient is older.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/ms345109(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#marsins_topic14) it states: "SqlClient provides the MultipleActiveResultSets connection string option. If set to false, MARS is not enabled for the session. If set to true or omitted, MARS is enabled." so following your answer, I understand this documentation is irrelevant, right?

Comment: The link I posted is to the current and correct documentation.